# Можно ли синхронизировать контракт Ethereum и кошелек МетаМаск со своей страницей?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, ethereum, криптовалюта

Есть контракт на базе Ethereum. Что бы с ним взаимодействовать (в данном случае мне нужно отправить функцию approve) мне нужно синхронизировать контракт с MetaMask, через нажатие кнопки Write Contract - Connect with Metamask:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И уже работать с ним.
Я хочу вынести функцию апрув к себе на страницу (на фронт-енд).

Грубо говоря, хочу полностью вынести работу с контрактом к себе на страницу.

Незнаю с чего начать, как это вообще происходит.
Может есть какое-то API - какой вообще стек для этого нужен?

Если придется заказать разработку, даже незнаю кого искать.